# Mean value among enumeration of non numeric types

Tags: combinatorics, means

I would like to ask if we have an enumeration of non numeric types, for example an enumeration of Strings and a certain frequency of appearance exists for each String, for example:In an experiment String0 appears n0 times, String1 n1 times etc.

Is it then possible to define the mean value among these Strings?

More strictly, there is an enumeration of k + 1 strings.
We have a random integer generator for integers [0 ... k]. 
We produce k + 1 random integers. Let's say the mean value of the experiment is k1 = 3.5. Each one of the k + 1 integers of the experiment is assigned to one of those strings of the enumeration. 
0 is assigned to String0, 1 is assigned to String1 .. k is assigned to Stringk. 
(There is a bijection among those k + 1 integers and the k + 1 strings of the enumeration). 
The k1 = 3.5 for example mean value of the experiment to which string of the enumeration corresponds?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question. String0 appears n0 times in what?

Comment: In an experment

Comment: What kind of experiment?

Comment: Somehow we have an enumeration of Strings each of which appears as such: String0 n0 times, ..., Stringk nk times. Lets say there is a bijection between each string and a collection of k+1 integers (between 0 and k)  there is an integer random generator among these k + 1 integers, we conduct the experiment k + 1 times of generating a random integer (among those k + 1 integers). We find the mean value of generating k + 1 times a random integer among the integers 0 ... k.  I ask if the mean value is k1 =  3.5 how do we find the Stringk1 which corresponds to k1 mean value of the above experiment?

Comment: I still don’t understand the question. Can you give a more specific example, or explain more clearly your motivation?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I edited the question. I believe it cannot be stated more analytically and more strictly.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly define the mean number of appearances of a string.  It is just the total number of strings divided by the number of different strings.  If you want to take the mean of two or more strings you can convert them to integers by viewing them as base $k$ numbers where $k$ is the number of different characters.  If your alphabet is lower case you could view $a$ as $1$, $z$ as $26$ and the mean as halfway between $m$ and $n$.  Is that useful?

Comment: I would like the mean of the experiment to be an already existing string among String0 which appears n0 times, String1 which appears n1 times .. Stringk which appears nk times. Not a string different from those alphanumerically in the midst of those strings. I don't know if the mean can be defined under those circumstances. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can certainly sort them alphabetically and find the median.  As long as you have at least three copies of each string the median will be a string in the list.  It also will be if you have an odd number of entries in the list.

Comment: I cannot see better solution than a alphabetical order!